# Wifi not switching ON!

Tags: 10.10, wireless, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 on an **hp dv4** and my wifi was working just fine(except the wifi led blinking) till yesterday. Now when I touch the wifi button it just won't switch ON!!! :o I didn't make any changes yesterday but updated my system today.

I have no idea what happened. Any clue???

I ran the command `sudo lshw` and got its output as:

> ```
> *-network DISABLED
>             description: Wireless interface
>             product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
>             vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
>             physical id: 0
>             bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
>             logical name: wlan0
>             version: 01
>             serial: 90:4c:e5:58:14:34
>             width: 64 bits
>             clock: 33MHz
>             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
>             ethernet physical wireless
>             configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k
>             driverversion=2.6.35-22-generic
>             firmware=N/A latency=0 link=yes
>             multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
>             resources: irq:17 memory:96400000-9640ffffmemory:96400000-9640ffff
> ```

The network is disabled?!? :o i tried to enable it by right clicking on network manager but the `Enable wireless` button has been greyed out.

I opened the file  /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state and found that the contents are

> `[main]
>   NetworkingEnabled=true
>   WirelessEnabled=false
>   WWANEnabled=true`

I tried to change `WirelessEnable=false` to `WirelessEnabled=true` but after reboot it resumed back to the same state.

Comment: That stupid touch-sensitive button has got to be the worst idea ever in the history of computer case design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rebooting. If it's still offline after the reboot, press the wifi button once more and restart again.

I had a similar issue with this on my dv5.

Comment: it didn't work for me :(

Comment: ok! it worked today :o